# Can server automatically response in Udp broadcasting event?

Tags: ios, network-programming

I am a beginner to iOS and network. What I want to do is sending a broadcast msg to a local network and getting all AP(hotspot) information back, like MAC address. I am just wondering if the AP(server) will automatically send the response back to the sender (like my iPhone) after I send a msg to "255.255.255.255" by Udp.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a networking question.
In short: use **DHCP** ([RFC 2131](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt)) to get the server IP and use **ARP** ([RFC 826](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826)) to obtain the MAC address associated to that IP. DHCP is connectionless (UDP), *but* ARP is a TCP/IP protocol.

The DHCP message (DHCPDISCOVER) will send something like "this is my MAC address(xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx), give me an IP addresss!" and the response (DHCPOFFER) from the server will contain the IP of the access point but not the MAC.

To get the MAC address of the AP, use ARP.
**ARP** stands for `Address Resolution Protocol` and is the mechanism used in the IP protocol over ethernet to obtain the MAC address of the destination. If the destination IP address belong to the *same* IP subnetwork the ARP module will send a broadcast ethernet message (ARP query) asking the MAC address of the destination IP address. If the destination is *not* on your local network the ARP module will send an ARP query using the IP address of your router.

Comment: Thank you for the kindly help. I will take a look. At the mean time, I am just thinking if I could use SSDP to get the server information.